# Initialize bean which has a field of inner class type

Tags: java, spring, inner-classes

I have a Spring bean with scope singleton. I want to inject into a bean which is instance of its inner class. I want it to be singleton as well. To do this I define outer class as Spring bean through annotation configuration and initialize filed of inner class through simple constructor invocation. My questions are: 
1. Is this is a correct approach? 
2. Will field B be populated only once on context startup, when singleton A is created?

```
@Service
public class A {

  private B b = new B();

  private class B() {
     public B(){}
  }

}
```

Comment: Note that the `B` instance is in no way related or managed by Spring. You won't be able to inject it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The pasted code can't even compile, but anyway there's nothing wrong with the general concept: Spring beans are objects created and managed by the Spring container, and they still obey all rules of the Java language and runtime.

When Spring constructs a bean of type `A`, the instance initializer is run, and it creates an object of type `B` (which has a link to the enclosing instance) and eventually stores the reference to such object in a field of A:

```
@Service
public class A {
  private B b = new B();
  private class B {}
}
```

<sub>That said, I don't like inner classes: sometimes they can be helpful and make your code easier to read and reason about, but in this case you want just one instance of B and the B constructor has zero arguments, so maybe it's just a group of methods that for some reason you want to put in a class definition on its own</sub>

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've corrected my code. Is this a good practice to initialize bean filed not through Spring context(xml, annotaion, Java) but explicit through new. I have a transformer class which transforms a huge object consisting of several blocks. I want to make an inner class where each method transforms each block, Outer class method loads some data and integrates results of inner transformer. The reason why I want inner class is because I can't change project package structure, I can't find appropriate location for inner helper Transformer.

Comment: It's just personal taste: if you are ok with it (or just constrained) it doesn't make any harm - I use inner classes a lot when defining UIs for example. In this case you want exactly one instance of each transformer and transformers don't take arguments on construction: they are effectively instance methods, and access is somewhat more difficult for eg testing